# How to ignore word positions in grams when using CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, nlp, countvectorizer

I have a corpus and I would like to get the frequency of all 2-grams. This is the code I am using :

```
vec = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2,2).fit(corpus)
bag_of_words = vec.transform(corpus)
sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0) 
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
```

The "words_freq" variable contains the frequency of each gram found in the corpus like :

```
print(words_freq)
[('green apple', 10), ('yellow apple',2), ('apple green',5)]
```

However, I would like to know how to get the frequency of each gram **without taking in account the order of words in the gram**.

For instance, "green apple" and "apple green" should be considered as the same gram and gives the result ('green apple',15).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet. Note that it will only work for bigrams.

```
words_freq = [('green apple', 10), ('yellow apple',2), ('apple green',5)]
alternate_words_freq = {}
for term, freq in words_freq:
    # Assume that bigrams are separated by a space
    # Reverse the bigram
    reverse_term = " ".join(term.split(" ")[::-1])

    if term in alternate_words_freq.keys():
        alternate_words_freq[term]+=freq
    elif reverse_term in alternate_words_freq.keys():
        alternate_words_freq[reverse_term]+=freq
    else:
        alternate_words_freq[term]=freq
# Prints [('green apple', 15), ('yellow apple', 2)]

print(list(alternate_words_freq.items()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question has been asked 2 years ago but I thought maybe someone would find this thread like I did today. :) The solution is quite easy, you just need to overwrite method `_word_ngrams` from `CountVectorizer`.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


class CustomCountVectorizer(CountVectorizer):
    def _word_ngrams(self, tokens, stop_words=None):
        """Turn tokens into a sequence of n-grams after stop words filtering"""
        # handle stop words
        if stop_words is not None:
            tokens = [w for w in tokens if w not in stop_words]

        # handle token n-grams
        min_n, max_n = self.ngram_range
        if max_n != 1:
            original_tokens = tokens
            if min_n == 1:
                # no need to do any slicing for unigrams
                # just iterate through the original tokens
                tokens = list(original_tokens)
                min_n += 1
            else:
                tokens = []

            n_original_tokens = len(original_tokens)

            # bind method outside of loop to reduce overhead
            tokens_append = tokens.append
            space_join = " ".join

            for n in range(min_n, min(max_n + 1, n_original_tokens + 1)):
                for i in range(n_original_tokens - n + 1):
                    ngram = space_join(sorted(original_tokens[i : i + n]))
                    tokens_append(ngram)

        return tokens
```

Thanks to using `sorted` the order of words in the n-gram is not taking into account. See the examples:

```
docs = ["black cat and cat black"]
cv = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2)).fit(docs)
print(cv.get_feature_names_out())
print(cv.transform(docs).toarray())
```

Output:

```
> ['and cat' 'black cat' 'cat and' 'cat black']
> [[1 1 1 1]]
```

And custom class:

```
docs = ["black cat and cat black"]
ccv = CustomCountVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2)).fit(docs)
print(ccv.get_feature_names_out())
print(ccv.transform(docs).toarray())
```

Output:

```
> ['and cat' 'black cat']
> [[2 2]]
```